# Async Socket Issue

Tags: node.js, electron

I m trying to read some server addresses and related port addresses from a json file within an electron application and trying to create a socket connection to test wheter application can connect to that servers with related port addresses. but whenever i run the application, first run it says all servers are up, second run the proper output, third one wrong etc.. at the end i think that theres a situation with the async socket method in a sync for next loop but couldnt figure out how can i fix it. I tried to create an array of sockets but it has also failed. can anyone advise me a method to overcome this situation ?

```
for(i=0; i < jsondata.length; i++){
const li = document.createElement('li');
const itemText = document.createTextNode(jsondata[i]['server'] + ':' + jsondata[i]['port']);
li.appendChild(itemText);
ul.appendChild(li);

let serverAddress = jsondata[i]['server'];
let portNumber = jsondata[i]['port'];

const socket = new net.createConnection(portNumber, serverAddress);
socket.on('connect', ()=>{
    console.log(serverAddress + ' connected');
    socket.end();
});
socket.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.log(serverAddress + ' failed');
    li.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    socket.end();
});
```

}

Comment: If you need a loop over some async functionality, write a recursive function and put the `async` method(s) there. So next loop happens when previous `async` call is resolved. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008897/node-js-twitter-api-cursors/46846606#46846606) is a sample.

Comment: if i didnt misunderstood, you advise to call an async function, which handles all socket creation, check events and awaits for the result, inside from the for loop right ?

Comment: Yes. Your loop doesn't wait for it's body to be executed as you expect from a blocking perspective.

Comment: what do you think about the solution below ? It works perfectly but theres something doesnt make sense for me; for loop begins and creates <li> object and continues with the socket creation. i have a list of servers some are active and some are inactive, so there should be a delay in socket creation. because of async functions it should continue for loop and iterate through the next loop item so after some time socket will fail and try to set the <li> text line-through. but at that time it should be somewhere on the next loops and

Comment: i dont set a class or id for the <li> object. but somehow it sets the style of correct <li> object. confused a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution, created an array for each socket, and it works. code is as follows;

```
var sockets = [];
for(i=0; i < jsondata.length; i++){
const li = document.createElement('li');
const itemText = document.createTextNode(jsondata[i]['server'] + ':' + jsondata[i]['port']);
li.appendChild(itemText);
ul.appendChild(li);

let serverAddress = jsondata[i]['server'];
let portNumber = jsondata[i]['port'];

sockets[i] = new net.createConnection(portNumber, serverAddress);
sockets[i].on('connect', ()=>{
    console.log(serverAddress + ' connected');
    sockets[i].end();
});
sockets[i].on('error', (err)=>{
    console.log(serverAddress + ' failed');
    li.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    sockets[i].end();
});
}
```